# Facing error A2052 with rotate instructions

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Because of a 64-bit system, I have to use DOSBOX to run 8086 assembly code. Every time I use any of the rotate instructions(ROR, ROL etc.), I get this error : Error A2052: Improper operand type. 
I have tried all the things I can think of and also google does not know about it.

```
.MODEL LARGE
.STACK 1000H
.DATA
LF DB 0AH
.CODE
MAIN PROC
MOV DX, 0002H
MOV CX, 0064H
BODY:
MOV BX, 0064H
SUB BX, CX
MOV AX, BX
DIV DL
CMP AH, 1H
JNE GO
PRINT:
ADD BX, 0H
AAA
OR BX, 3030H
ROL BX, 4
MOV AL, BL
MOV AH, 1H
INT 21H
ROL BX, 4
MOV AL, BL
MOV AH, 1H
INT 21H
LEA DX, LF
MOV AH, 9H
INT 21H
GO: LOOP BODY
MAIN ENDP 
END
```

and I'm getting this error message:

[image]

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: @fuz included the code...Have a look at it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 8086 only supports shift by 1 or by CL. You are trying to shift by a constant greater than one.

Comment: Thus you should use `.model 686` or something, because the OP is using DOSBOX and not limited to baseline 8086 instructions.  (imm8 shift/rotate counts were added in 186 or 286.)

Comment: But incase I want to stuck with 8086...Do I need to shift 4 times? since I can't use CL

Comment: Yes I was trying to rotate it four times...thanks it did the job

Comment: I suggest you use a different register instead of cx for your loop counter, don't use the loop instruction, just use dec/jnz, and then you can use cl for your shift count.